# Azure blob storage save Dto

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to save some objects (DTO) directly to Azure Blob storage. I found a solution using BinaryFormatter, but according to this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide), it's not recommended.

So, I think I will convert the data to JSON and compress it. Is there another way to save objects directly to a blob?

Thank you

Comment: there is not much to add to that article. Don't use BinaryFormatter but one of the alternatives proposed, like JSON.

Comment: @silent i ask if exists any changes how to save objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***By serialising and compressing your DTO object, you can compress the resulting JSON data. Use compressedStream like the code below to upload the blob in async.***

**Code:-**

> ````cs
> using System.Text.Json; using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
>
> namespace MyNamespace {
>     public class MyDto
>     {
>         public int Num { get; set; }
>         public string Place { get; set; }
>         public DateTime Startedat { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     class Program
>     {
>         static async Task Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             //Create a MyDto object using this code.
>
>              var myObject = new MyDto
>             {
>                 Num = 3,
>                 Place = "dto",
>                 Startedat = DateTime.UtcNow
>             };
>
>             // Convert the object to JSON.
>
>             var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
>             var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject, options);
>
>             // Compress JSON
>             using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
>             using var gzipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
>             using var writer = new StreamWriter(gzipStream);
>             writer.Write(json);
>             writer.Flush();
>
>             var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxtu7OGErfF4WsrLocnQOsxAqVg0azDou1vEATj8osRx+3o+ASt1/hvig==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
>             var containerName = "siliconcon";
>             var blobName = "siliconvalley";
>             var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
>             var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
>             var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
>             compressedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
>             await blobClient.UploadAsync(compressedStream);
>
>             Console.WriteLine("Object uploaded successfully!");
>         }
>     } } ```
> ````

> I have used this [link](https://code-maze.com/csharp-object-into-json-string-dotnet/) to initiate JsonSerializerOptions class in this line :- var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }; in the above code and also referred these [MS document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0) samples.

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]